# Setting Struct equal to a function that returns the same struct

Tags: c, struct, variable-assignment

So I'm on the last steps of my project, and I have to return a struct from a function, so I can use it in main.
Relevant code can be seen:

```
typedef struct SomeProduct {
    int itemNum;
    char itemName[21];
    double unitPrice;
    int stockQty;
    int restockQty;
    struct SomeProduct *next;
} SProduct;

 struct llpro {

 SProduct data;
 struct llpro *next;
 };

////////////////////SKIP LINES to identifier

SProduct findItem(struct llpro *head,int num);

///////////////////SKIP LINES to assignment that fails. head is the proper
////////////////// pointeritemspurchased is an int.

SProduct steve;
steve=findItem(head,newv.itemsPurchased[y]);

//////////////////Skip Lines to method

SProduct findItem(struct llpro *head,int num)
{
    while(head!=NULL)
    {
       if(head->data.itemNum==num)
       {
         SProduct paul;
         paul=head->data;
         return paul;
       }
    }
}
```

Anytime I try to compile it I get linker errors saying that they are never defined. Then when I take out the identifier, I get a message saying that steve and paul are incompatible types, even though they are both SProducts. Please help!
Id also like to clarify, what im trying to do is search through a linked list of Sproducts, and pull the information from the one that shares the item number with the one im searching for. The linker error says "undefined reference to 'finditem' in function printsum

Comment: Can you add the errors too? Also, your loop in `findItem` is infinite if `head` is not `NULL`; The reason being you never change `head`.

Comment: Im not sure how I would go about adding them but when the code does not include the line:
SProduct findItem(struct llpro *head,int num);
I get a message saying incompatible types in assignment.
When i do i get one saying
Linker Error

Comment: Having `struct llpro` helps a bit.  Now we need to work out where you are assigning `steve` to `paul` or vice versa.

Comment: Are you sure that SProduct is actually defined in the scope you're trying to use it in? maybe you forgot a `# include` directive.

Comment: Steve=findItem(....) is where he is being assigned to paul, because paul is being returned. Correct?

Comment: Yes, the issue is i cant include the entire file or else bad things could happen to my grade, so, I know its in scope. I use it in tons of other places.

Comment: And this code is all in a single source file? What is the exact linker error? Please add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

This code compiles under GCC 4.1.2 with options `-Wall -Wextra -std=c99`:

```
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct SomeProduct
{
    int                 itemNum;
    char                itemName[21];
    double              unitPrice;
    int                 stockQty;
    int                 restockQty;
    struct SomeProduct *next;
} SProduct;

struct llpro
{
    SProduct data;
    struct llpro *next;
};

SProduct findItem(struct llpro *head,int num);

int main(void)
{
    struct llpro *head = 0;
    SProduct steve;
    steve = findItem(head, 1);
}

SProduct findItem(struct llpro *head, int num)
{
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->data.itemNum == num)
        {
            SProduct paul;
            paul = head->data;
            return paul;
        }
    }
    SProduct alan = { 0, "", 0.0, 0, 0, 0 };
    return alan;
}
```

The main changes are using `1` in place of your complex value for the argument to `findItem()` and the addition of a `return` to the end of `findItem()`.  Neither affects any assignments.

So, assuming you have problems, you've mis-excerpted your code and not shown us the lines causing the trouble.

Comment: Jonathan could I email you my actual code? Like I said, i cant post it online. it would be unedited, and i think more use.

Comment: Inspecting the actual code, the function findItem() was not declared before it was used, and the actual implementation was nested inside another function, after the point of use.

Comment: The question was updated to include the information _The linker error says "`undefined reference to 'finditem' in function printsum`"_.  That suggests that you wrote '`finditem`' instead of '`findItem`'; C is case-sensitive.  (It also suggests you omitted the critical code, which is clearly the function `printsum`.)